# I've tried the following infinite loop in my code, but it seem not work

Tags: python

I've tried the following infinite loop in my code, but it seem not work, please help, thanks !

Code:

```
import time
import sys
from qt4 import QtWebKit
from qt4 import QtCore
from qt4 import QtGui
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

while True: 

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia

class Render(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        QtWebKit.QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

url = 'http://youneednothing.com/'
r = Render(url)
content = unicode(r.frame.toHtml())

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print soup
time.sleep(10)
```

I've put the following for looping of my code, but it seem not work.

```
 import time

 Wihle True:
 [my code]
 time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Well.. it's very clear.

Comment: i've not idea to fix, since i've checked the syntax are ok, and when i take out all looping code, my code is work fine !

Comment: indentation is needed the line after the while True:, also you have spelt while wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont need to execute class every time .

```
import time
import sys
from qt4 import QtWebKit
from qt4 import QtCore
from qt4 import QtGui
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia

class Render(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        QtWebKit.QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

while True: 
    url = 'http://youneednothing.com/'
    r = Render(url)
    content = unicode(r.frame.toHtml())

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    print soup
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this is an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    print soup
    time.sleep(10)
```

In python you have to use tabulations or whitespace to define blocks of code. In this case the `print soup` and `time.sleep(10)` make up the block beneath the `while True:` thereby defining the code that needs to be looped infinitely.

Have a look at Python tutorials regarding the `while` and other control flow statements, for example [3.2 First Steps Towards Programming](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) (second bullet point).

Answer (score 1):

Python uses indentation to separate different code blocks. So you need to indent the code after while statement, like you did in the class definition.

So the code should look like this:

```
while True:
    [your code]
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recommendation for your code, as I thought the other answers were sufficient, but this can be handy.
At the top where you import things into your module you have:

```
from qt4 import QtWebKit
from qt4 import QtCore
from qt4 import QtGui
```

this can be refined down to:

```
from qt4 import QtWebKit, QtCore, QtGui
```

when importing it is not 'good' to import more than one thing on one line, except with the `from ... import ..., ..., ...` technique.
Just a handy tip :)